# Retrieving sitecore users filtered by domain (Tuning)

Tags: performance, sitecore, membership-provider

So i have a Sitecore website that has let's say 10000 users distributed over 2 domains.

I want a solution for retrieving the users from one domain only but fast. Currently it is quite heavy even for the Sitecore User manager to do that.

If that is simple then i want to also query over a field from the user profile.

I have tried something like this:

```
var allUsers = UserManger.GetUsers().Where(user => user.Domain != null && user.Domain.Name.ToLower().Equals("extranet")).ToArray();
```

But that can take 30 seconds or more if i add extra filters.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the code you're running, you can also run the following:

```
var allUsers = DomainManager.GetDomain("extranet").GetUsers();
```

So instead of having to go through all users in all domains to check whether they are in the Extranet domain, you'll already have the correct domain

Comment: Was just my thought. I will give it a try.

Comment: I have tried but still performance not optimal.I have about 5000 users returned in 9 seconds. If i want to get the ones who do not have the email field filled then the performance goes to about 45-50 seconds. Considering i need to check more of the user profile fields the performance will get worse.

Comment: @alinulms You can do SQL query directly to the membership table where all profile fields are stored.